# error CS0119: 'ServiceClient' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-reference

I am getting  **error CS0119: 'ServiceClient' is a type, which is not valid in the given context** in my project . In my project I have a web reference and in that I'm getting this error . The details are below. Please help guys as I don't understand how to solve this .

**CODE**

```
    private ServiceClient _client;
    private ServiceClient ProfileServiceClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_client == null)
            {
                //Log.Trace("Initiating Profile client");

                var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                ServiceClient _client = new ServiceClient ();
                watch.Stop();

                Log.Debug("Initiating Profile took " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " miliseconds");
            }
            return _client;
         }
      }


      public AuthenticatedUser ResolveUser(string Id)
    {
        try
        {
            //Log.BusinessTask(string.Format("Trying to resolve '{0}' via Profile", vcnId));
            var temp = ServiceClient .getProfileUser(Id, Config.ProfileAppName);

            if (temp == null)
            {
                Log.BusinessTask(string.Format("No user found in profile with '{0}' as  ID", Id));
                var dummyUser = new AuthenticatedUser()
                {
                    Id = Id,
                    Email = string.Empty,
                    FirstName = Id,
                    LastName = string.Empty
                };

                dummyUser.Roles.Add("Viewer");

                Log.BusinessTask("Closing Profile client connection");
                ServiceClient .Dispose();

                return dummyUser;
            }

            Log.BusinessTask("Profile user found, mapping properties");
            var result = new AuthenticatedUser
            {
                Id = temp.userNr,
                Email = temp.email,
                FirstName = temp.firstName,
                LastName = temp.lastName
            };

            result.Roles.Add("Viewer");

            Log.BusinessTask("Profile user found, mapping roles and applications");
            var animatrix = ServiceClient .getTheAnimatrix(Id, Config.ProfileAppName, 0, null, null);

            if (animatrix != null)
            {
                foreach (var matrix in animatrix)
                {
                    if (matrix.authorisations != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var m in matrix.authorisations)
                        {
                            if (m.value.strValue == "Developer Documentation")
                            {
                                if (!result.Roles.Any(x => x.Equals("Developer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                                    result.Roles.Add("Developer");
                            }

                            if (m.value.strValue == "IsIt Documentation")
                            {
                                if (!result.Roles.Any(x => x.Equals("IsIt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                                    result.Roles.Add("IsIt");
                            }

                            if (m.characteristic == "Managed Application")
                            {
                                if (matrix.role.roleName.Contains("DEVELOPER"))
                                    result.Applications.Add("Developer" + "/" + m.value.strValue);
                                else
                                    result.Applications.Add("IsIt" + "/" + m.value.strValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            Log.BusinessTask("Closing Profile client connection");
            ServiceClient .Dispose();

            Log.BusinessTask("Returning User object");
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(string.Format("Couldn't reach the PROFILE auth webservice : {0}", e));
        }

        return new AuthenticatedUser { FirstName = "Viewer", Id = "none" };
    }
```

**In Referrence.cs file**

```
         public ServiceClient () {
          this.Url = 
          global::ProxyComponent.Properties.Settings.Default.ProxyComponent_Services_ServiceClient _ServiceClient ;
          if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
            this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
          }
           else {
            this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
          }
        }
```

I am getting error in this particular line **ServiceClient _client = new ServiceClient ();** . Any solution for this error or any clue ? In method AuthenticatedUser ResolveUser(string Id) line var temp = ServiceClient .getProfileUser(Id, Config.ProfileAppName) ServiceClient throws error like threw an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' .
**InnerException    {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}**

**SOLUTION**
Okay I found my solution . I have to change this line

```
   var temp = ServiceClient .getProfileUser(Id, Config.ProfileAppName);
```

to this

```
     _client = new ServiceClient();
     var temp = _client.getProfileUser(Id, Config.ProfileAppName);
```

Comment: Are you missing a using statement?

Comment: You only want `_client = new ServiceClient();`, you don't want a new local variable.

Comment: tried this but same error

Comment: This code does not give that compiler error. Read [ask] and create a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

It looks almost like the compiler is confusing the service client with another type. Maybe try using ServiceClient with the full namespace? Something like FullProjectNamespace.ServiceClient _serviceClient = new...

Comment: That would yield a different compiler error: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type FooNamespace.ServiceClient to BarNamespace.ServiceClient.

Comment: @CodeCaster any clue to solve this??

Comment: Why the downvote dude? With your edit you've proven my point and were using the wrong type.